# How to use a structure as a key in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, stl, operator-overloading

i'm trying to print for every given interval , its number of occurence in the inputdata , for example for the input : 
4
1 5
6 8
6 8
4 7
the program should print :
1 5 : 1
6 8 : 2
4 7 : 1
here is my code

```
struct Interval 
{ 
    long unsigned int start, end; 
}; 
bool operator<(const Interval& i1, const Interval& i2) 
{ 
    bool renvoie = true;;
    if(i1.start < i2.start)
    {
        renvoie = true;
    }
    else if(i1.start== i2.start && i1.end>=i2.end)
        renvoie = true;
    else
        renvoie = false;
    return renvoie;
} 
bool operator==(const Interval& i1, const Interval& i2)
{
    return (i1.start==i2.start && i1.end==i2.end);
}
int main()
{
int nbr;
cin>>nbr;
   map<Interval, int> occurence;
  for(int i=0;i<nbr;i++)
  {
     Interval jetable;
     cin>>jetable.start;
     cin>>jetable.end;
     occurence[jetable]++;
  }

    for(map<Interval,int>::iterator it = occurence.begin(); it!=occurence.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << (it->first).start <<" " <<(it->first).end<<" "<<(it->second)<<endl;
    }


}
```

the problem , is that two same interval are considered different , why ??

Comment: Tip: what happens if `i1.start == i2.start` and `i1.end == i2.end` in your `operator <`? What is the result, `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's what your comparator says. Your overload returns `true` if the same object gets passed as both parameters. Your `<` overload, returns `true` in that situation. This means that your `<` overload says that the first value is less than the second value, which, by definition, cannot be the case when they're equal.

Simply change it to return false in that situation (which is simply sufficient by changing the `>=` to `>`).